# Large Negative r-Squared Scores using Cross-Validation

Tags: python, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I am working working with the [World Happiness Report](https://www.kaggle.com/unsdsn/world-happiness) dataset from Kaggle. When using either `cross_val_score` or `GridSearchCV` from `sklearn`, I get very large negative r2 scores. My first thought was that the models I was using were SEVERELY over-fitting (it is a small dataset), but when I performed cross-validation using `KFold` to split the data, I got reasonable results.

You can view an example of what I am talking about in this [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1d8Fo5BajtxssLtLgN473YFbBT-TXJCwP?usp=sharing). The relevant code is also shown below.

**Using cross_val_score**

```
model = LinearRegression()
print(cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='r2', cv=5))
```

Output: `[-5.57285067 -5.9477523  -6.23988074 -8.84930385 -2.39521998]`

**Using KFold**

```
model = LinearRegression()
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
scores = []

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X)):
    X_train = X[train_index,:]
    y_train = y[train_index]
    X_test = X[test_index,:]
    y_test = y[test_index]

    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    test_score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    scores.append(round(test_score, 6))

print(scores)
```

Output: `[0.829785, 0.774577, 0.762708, 0.661945, 0.727391]`

**Some Additional Observations**

- It doesn't seem to matter what type of model I use. I still get very large negative scores when using `cross_val_score`.
- I created a synthetic dataset that was approximately the same size of the World Happiness dataset just to try some things out. In that case, I **did not** get large negative r2 scores from `cross_val_score`. This is shown in the Google Colab notebook that I shared above.
- I notice that the magnitude of the negative results I get using `cross_val_score` is greatly affected by the number of folds I use. Increasing the number of folds significantly increases the magnitude.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you are fitting your whole data to it, it seems the cross_val_score awaits a predefined train_test_split object. Ignore the part with 'bla' :-). Btw. it is also the kaggle data. I used it in one of my own notebooks.

[image: Solve]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but I don't think that it quite gets to the core of the issue. First, the primary purpose of cross-validation is to avoid needing to create a train-test split. New splits are created during cross-validation. Second, you are not providing a "train_test_split" object to `cross_val`score`. The objects `X_train` and `y_train` are numpy arrays, just like the original `X` and `y` arrays.

Comment: Your comment did help me to discover the true source of the issue, however. The data is not shuffled by `cross_val_score`. I did not know this previously. Since the observations are provided in order of the target variable in this dataset, the folds created by `cross-val_score` each consider of similar observations and are not representative of the dataset as a whole. I was able to resolve the issue by shuffling the data before using `cross_val_score`. 

Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Well if you see it that way: Xtrain is not a numpy array it is  pandas DataFrame object... which is an array like shape. But I'm glad I could help even you tried to correct me in every sentence ...

Comment: Please try not to take things so personally. I appreciate your effort to help, and was not trying to be critical of you, but the points I made were correct. 

In reference to your comment about arrays vs DataFrames... If you pass arrays to `train_test_split`, you will get back out arrays. If you pass in DataFrames, you will get back DataFrames. I said that `X_train` was an array because in my case, it was. I has created `X` to be an array, meaning that `X_train` was an array.

(continued)

Comment: But if I has been working with DataFrames, my point still stands: The datatype of X and X_train will be the same (both arrays or both DataFrames). You suggested that `cross_val_score` expected a `train_test_split` object, but that is not the issue. The type of the objects are the same with or without using `train_test_split`. 

As I explained, the reason why `train_test_split` works in this situation is because it shuffles the rows before performing the split.

Comment: That however is right, but stating your point (numpy, dataFrame) was not part of the solution ;-) and you could have left it out. Or in other words: It's not what you say, but how you say it. I hope you lecture your students in a different way ...if someone cames up with an idea even it is not 100%

Answer (score -1):

Solved! The issue is that the observations in this dataset are ordered with respect to the value of the target variable and `cross_val_score` does not shuffle the data provided to it. As a result, each fold contains a set of values that are similar to each other and don't represent the entire dataset.